Draw $5$ numbers from $A = \{1, 1.5, \dots, 9.5, 10\}$ with replacement. What is the most likely average?
Suppose there's a set  $$A = \{1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10\}. $$ Now, $5$ numbers are drawn from $A$ (repetition allowed). If $x$ is the average of those $5$ numbers, which number has the highest probability of being $x$?
(NOTE: When simulated, I observed that number 5 and 5.5 were repeated the most! Mind you that I don't necessarily want your answers to match to the result, just want a theoretical answer to the problem  )

Getting maximum likliehood is often tricky...the expected average is $5.225$ (I did it quickly, so that might be a off).  But of course that doesn't mean that numbers near that are likely to get repeated.  That said, I'm surprised you see $7,7.5$ a lot.   I just ran a quick simulation, and saw those (exact) numbers very rarely.

And, of course, If $S$ is any selection, then $11-S$ must be equally likely. so  $7, 7.5$  should occur as often as $3.5,4$.   To be sure, that symmetry argument suggests that the expected average should be $\frac {11}2=5.5$ so perhaps my hasty computation was incorrect.

I mean, it's a simulation so even I can't get a hold. But, what number repeated the most in your simulation?

I got close to uniformity around $5.5$.  Dropped off considerably towards the edges.

Why don't you define $A$ as ${2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 20}$? That's much easier to handle :-)

@Dominique I mean : \ , Idk, just wanted to do that. I don't actually have a specific logical reason, but the thing is that I was watching this reality show where u have to score yourself out of 10 (score could be .5 decimal) and if ur score and the average of judge's score are a match, u win. I just wanted a mathematical answer to that : )

Have you ever seen or done the computation that if you throw two dice, the number 7 is most likely to occur as the sum? (As a result, 3.5 would be the most likely as the avarage of two dice.) The idea behind the computation here is similar

The distribution of the sum of five numbers drawn at random (with replacement) from the $19$ in your set is the $5$-fold convolution of the uniform distribution on those $19$ numbers. Writing code to perform this convolution isn't a difficult task.  It's not necessary to do this, however, to work out the most probable value of the sum.  The sum itself could be any of the $91$ numbers $\ 5+\frac{n}{2}\ $ for $\ n=0,1,\dots,90\ ,$ and the most probable value will be the one exactly in the middle, where $\ n=45\ $—namely $\ 27.5\ .$ The most probable value for the average of the $5$ numbers is therefore $\ \frac{27.5}{5}=5.5\ .$
Edit
I've now calculated the actual distribution of $\ x\ .$ The values of the three largest probabilities are
\begin{align}
P(x=5.5)&=\frac{78151}{19^5}\approx0.03156\\
P(x=5.4)&=P(x=5.6)\\
&=\frac{77925}{19^5}\approx0.03147\ .
\end{align}
Generalisation
The interesting phenomenon mentioned by lulu in the comments is worth remarking on.  If $\ X_1,X_2,\dots,X_d\ ,$ with $\ d\ge2\ ,$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed over $\ a\ $ equally spaced atoms, $\ \ell,$$\,\ell+r,$$\,\ell+2r,$$\,\dots,$$\,\ell+(a-1)r\ ,$ then the distribution of their sum is the $\ d$-fold convolution of that distribution. This latter distribution has $\ d(a-1)+1\ ,$ atoms,$\ d\ell,$$\,d\ell+r,$$\ \,\dots,$$\,d\ell+d(a-1)r\ ,$ and mean $\ \mu=d\ell+\frac{d(a-1)r}{2}\ .$ If $\ d(a-1)\ $ is even, then the number of atoms is odd, the middle one is the mean $\ \mu\ ,$ and this is the most probable value of the sum. If $\ d(a-1) $ is odd, however (requiring both $\ d\ $ and $\ a-1\ $ to be odd), then the mean $\ \mu\ $ is not an atom and therefore cannot be the value of the sum. In this case, there are two equiprobable atoms, $\ \mu-\frac{r}{2}\ $ and $\ \mu+\frac{r}{2}\ ,$ on either side of the mean which are more probable than any other.
For the problem posed by the OP, Mune, $\ \ell=1,$$\,a=19,$$\,r=\frac{1}{2}\ $ and $\ d=5\ .$ Since $\ d(a-1)\ $ is even in this case, the most probable value of the sum is the mean, $\ 27.5\ .$
For the case of three fair dice, raised by lulu in the comments, $\ \ell=1,a=6,r=1\ $ and $\ d=3\ .$ Since $\ d(a-1)\ $ is odd, the mean $\ 10.5\ $ is not an atom of the distribution in this case, and therefore not a possible value of the sum. The two most probable values of the sum are the two atoms $\ 10=$$\,10.5-0.5\ $ and $\ 11=10.5+0.5\ .$

It is, of course, equally true that $5.5$ is the expected value for a single draw, but that does not make it the most likely number to observe.  Indeed, for a single draw, each value is equally likely.

For a single draw, sure. But once you've done more than one draw, $x$ is no longer uniformly distributed.  After $\ d\ $ draws, it can have any one of $\ 18d+1\  $ values, $\  1+\frac{n}{2d}\ ,$ for $\ n=0,1,2,\dots,18d\ ,$ and the middle one, at $\ n=9d\ $—namely $5.5$—is always the most probable (even if its actual probability might be quite small).

For a toss of three fair dice, the average is $10.5$ which is not a possible outcome.  To be sure,  I believe the claim and (my) simulations confirm it,  but it's worth a proof

It turned out to be harder than I thought it would be to find a published proof.  There's one in this paper, however, uploaded to arKiv in $2007,$ and updated in $2018.$ I presume it's an updated version of the one by the same author published in Probability in the Engineering & Informational Sciences in $2011$

The number having the highest probablity of being the average of 5 randomly picked numbers in Arithmetic Progression is the average of the middle 5 values.
The set has 19 elements [odd number of elements], thus the average of the middle 5 values will be the [(n+1)/2]th term i.e. the 10th term.
Therefore, x = 5.5
If the number of terms were even, x will be equal to the average of the middle 2 values.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

prove the first statement of ur answer bro...

The average toss of a fair die is $3.5$ which is obviously not the most common toss.
